# How to change decimal(18,2) to decimal(38,35) using ef core code first

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I have a simple question. By default, decimal data will be stored as `decimal(18, 2)`, but I want to change it to `decimal(38, 35)` using EF Core code-first.

How can I do that?

```
public decimal OrderIndex { get; set; }
```

in SQL Server?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this.

```
entityBuilder.Property(r => r.OrderIndex)
            .HasColumnType("decimal(38,35)")
            .IsRequired(true);
```